# kivy display blocking raspberry pi screen saver

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3, screensaver

I am running a python application with kivy as the graphical interface.  I find that during the application, even with screen updates, the screen saver makes the screen go blank (raspberry pi).  Is there a way to stop this from happening?  Is there a way to "fake" a screen touch so that the OS believe that the screen is still used and doesn't go black?  I don't want to turn off the screen saver for the OS as a whole, just during this application.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57552 ?

Comment: or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/753/62841 ?

Comment: or https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/69614/62841

Comment: Thank you,  I was trying to avoid turning off the screen saver, and just have it "disabled" while running Kivy/Python Code. I have not found a solution for this yet.From what I have read, it doesn't seem to be possible.  I implemented the lightdm solution which seems to have turned off the screensaver.  I am concerned with ruining the screen if left on for long periods of time. I was hoping that kivy would be able to "stop" the screen saver from coming on.

Comment: Update, kivy now has an allow_screensaver parameter now which will stop devices from sleeping/turning on screen savers when enabled. found here: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html?highlight=allow_screensaver#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.allow_screensaver it can be added to individual sub-routines instead of the whole application

Comment: I think you should post it as an answer so that somebody else sees it if they are searching for the same problem. If you are to lazy, I can post it as an answer as well.